# Finding the base of a given vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble formally finding the  vector base of : 
$$U= \{ X \in  3\times 3\text{ matrices over }\mathbb R | X^T= -X\}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection $\operatorname{Sym}_{3}(\mathbb R)$ of *symmetric matrices* is
$$
\operatorname{Sym}_{3}(\mathbb R)=\left\{A\in\mathcal M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R):A^\top = A\right\}
$$
It is a subspace of $\mathcal M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$. Since every symmetric matrix is of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & d \\
b & c & e \\
d & e & f
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
we see that $\operatorname{Sym}_{3}(\mathbb R)$ has dimension $6$ and has basis
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The subspace you are asking about is the subspace of *skew-symmetric* matrices
$$
\operatorname{Skew}_{3}(\mathbb R)
=\left\{A\in\mathcal M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R):A^\top = -A\right\}
$$ 
Every skew-symmetric matrix is of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 &  a & b \\
-a &  0 & c \\
-b & -c & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Can you mimic what I've done for $\operatorname{Sym}_{3}(\mathbb R)$ to find a basis for $\operatorname{Skew}_{3}(\mathbb R)$?

For completeness, I've included a basis for $\operatorname{Skew}_{3}(\mathbb R)$ below.

> $$ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\-1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \quad\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0 \\-1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \quad\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So i could say that a representing matrix could be {(0,x,y),(-x,0,z),(-y,-z,0)} (how can i write matrices like you did?), then we would have x*{(0,1,0),(-1,0,0),(0,0,0)+y*{(0,0,1),(0,0,0),(-1,0,0)}+z{(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,-1,0)} and those would be the basis?

Comment: Do you see the relationship between the representative matrix for $\operatorname{Sym}_3(\mathbb R)$ and the basis I give for $\operatorname{Sym}_3(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: so is the basis  [{(0,1,0),(-1,0,0),(0,0,0)},{(0,0,1),(0,0,0),(-1,0,0)},{(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,-1‌​,0)}]? or did i miss something?

Comment: That looks correct!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First try to discover what the dimension of $U$ should be. How many independent formulas does $X^T = -X$ give you?